# Inserting code from Contentscript.js (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

I am Developing the Politics & Information Google Chrome Extension but I have run into a problem, I am attempting to insert a JS Script into one of the div's of the Webpage, the result is nothing, absolutely nothing pops up

I know i have the right area because if I use += "Hello"; it displays the text there properly, but when I actually do +="" the script doesn't seem to run. To all them devs out there, any suggestions?

How I am doing it:

theinfotable.children[0].innerHTML += '';
JavaScript (Google Chrome Extension inserted from the Contentscripts.js file)

I can see that the Code Inserted, but the script still doesn't seem to load: (And I know this code works when I have my own page instead of inserting)
http://oi61.tinypic.com/2irkx9c.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, the page was blocking my script as "Insecure" at the top right there was a little Shield Icon and after clicking on it I just had to put "Show Insecure Scripts" and it popped up.

(If anyone feels like telling me so people don't have to do this, that'd be great :D) I would rather people just have it pop up instead of having to stay for it to pop up

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use .innerHTML, have you tried creating a new element and appending it?

```
var injectable = document.createElement("script");
injectable.innerHTML = "console.log('Injected!');" // Your script here
// or injectable.src = "location" if you'd rather link
theinfotable.children[0].appendChild(injectable);
```

I'm not entirely sure why this occurs, if I had to guess it's an idiosyncrasy in how things are parsed or a security measure, but appendChild should do the trick. Basically, from what I understand it's the difference between

**innerHTML +=**: converting HTML to a string, and adding to that string, and re-parsing that string with new content

and...

**appendChild**: creating a DOM node, appending said DOM node, recalculating/refreshing the document for styling recalculations.

And somewhere in the parsing, your new script info is ignored.

Comment: I tried this out but it still didn't seem to work. var injectable = document.createElement("script");
injectable.injectable = "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://srvpub.com/adServe/banners?tid=26300_55726_1"></script>" // Your script here
// or injectable.src = "location" if you'd rather link
theinfotable.children[0].appendChild(injectable);

Comment: I used '' instead of "" and it no longer gave off an error, but the ad still isn't popping up

Comment: The Script: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://srvpub.com/adServe/banners?tid=26300_55726_1"></script>

Comment: I don't think you realize how this is working.

`document.createElement("script")` creates a script node for you to work with.

What you would need to do is:

`var injectable = document.createElement("script");`

`injectable.src = "http://srvpub.com/adServe/banners?tid=26300_55726_1";`

`theinfotable.children[0].appendChild(injectable);`

Because when you .attribute of the  created node, you are modifying an an attribute (.innerHTML) of the script node you created.

Comment: The ad still isn't appearing, I don't understand why it's not working (Note I Copy and Pasted your code)

Comment: The injection is going to a div, and if I do innerHTML += "TEST"; I can still see that the text "TEST" Pops up, but then I did your code, and nothing happened. Is it the way Im defining the variable? theinfotable = document.getElementById('rightcolumn');